# How to draw surface of a solid model which have inside points that must not be drawned?

Tags: javascript, three.js, computational-geometry, mesh, delaunay

I am trying to draw a geometry of a solid mesh which has inside nodes. From my research I understood that I can use delaunay triangulation for connecting vertices to produce faces. However my data has additional nodes that positioned at the inside of mesh. For creating faces I have to filter out those vertices while they shouldn't be drawn. How can I filter them out? Are there any stable algorithm for that purpose?

Note that I am new to computational geomtery. So there may be easier approach to that issue.

I am using three.js for drawing. Therefore you can suggest me three.js modules too solution.

Comment: It depends if you will be using a 3D rendering engine (OpenGL) or roll your own algorithm for hidden parts removal.

Comment: Please review these help center topics: [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [`What topics can I ask about here?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [`What types of questions should I avoid asking?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also, [take a look at this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). It seems like you're still researching. Once you encounter problems while ***implementing*** a solution, come back, share some code, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847752/generate-mesh-from-points-three-js/41859008#41859008