# Generate a mesh from points Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to generate a mesh from points. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847752/generate-mesh-from-points-three-js) the way to generate the mesh is,

```
var mesh = new THREE.ConvexGeometry( vertices_array );
```

In [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_convex.html) they've declared the `vertices_array` like below

```
var vertices = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry( 10 ).vertices;
```

What I need to understand is, how to define the `vertices_array` for points created using `THREE.BufferGeometry` with the code below.

Thank you very much

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/WebGL.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ConvexGeometry.js"></script>
        <script src="js/QuickHull.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

        if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {
            document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );
        }
        var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45.0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 5, 3500 );
            camera.position.z = 2500;
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            createScene();
        }

        function createScene() {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
                var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                var positions = [];


                for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i ++ ) {
                    for ( var j = 0; j < 20; j ++ ) {
                    var y = j;
                    var x = i; 
                    var z = 0;
                    positions.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z) );
                    //positions.push( x, y, z );

                    }
                }


                //geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

                //var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000} );
                //points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
                //scene.add( points );

                var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff,} );
                var meshGeometry = new THREE.ConvexBufferGeometry( positions );
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( meshGeometry, meshMaterial );
                scene.add( mesh );


        }


        function animate( time ) {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create points, or a mesh? If you're trying to make a mesh, why are you using `THREE.Points()`? Also, If you're trying to create convex geometry out of a `Float32BufferAttribute`, you should be using `ConvexBufferGeometry`

Comment: I've created the points using above code. I want to create the mesh using that points.

Comment: @brabbit640 For a mesh you need not only points, you need also primitives, e.g. triangles. How should the points form triangles?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm not sure how. Could you please explain a bit more? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Here all the points are located in a one plane, if that helps...

Comment: @brabbit640 It is unclear what you want to achieve. May be [`THREE.ConvexBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/geometries/ConvexBufferGeometry)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I want to achieve [`THREE.ConvexBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/geometries/ConvexBufferGeometry) with the points I've generated by the code.

Comment: @brabbit640 For a [`THREE.ConvexBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/geometries/ConvexBufferGeometry), the points have to be an array of [`THREE.Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3). `positions.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z) );` ... `var geometry = new THREE.ConvexBufferGeometry( positions );`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I added the whole code so you can understand my problem better. When I use `positions.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z) );` instead of `positions.push( x, y, z ); ` I can only see 1 triangle :(